# Python string indexing / printing error

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to get a dna reading script to work properly, right now only partially. This takes a string of 'A', 'T', 'C', or 'G' characters and finds genes based on whether the substring starts with 'ATG' and ends with either 'TAA', 'TGA', 'TAG'. printAllGenes() prints out a dna strand (the identified substring) on a new line for each one found and continues through the input string until there's no more to be found. It seems printAllGenes() fails to complete execution because of an error in the else clause of findStopCodon().

```
gene_sequence = 'AACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTAACCCTCACCCTTCTAACTGGACTCTGACCCTGATTGTTGAGGGCTGCAAAGAGGAAGAATTTTATTTACCGTCGCTGTGGCCCCGAGTTGTCCCAAAGCGAGGTAATGCCCGCAAGGTCTGTGCTGATCAGGACGCAGCTCTGCCTTCGGGGTGCCCCTGGACTGCCCGCCCGCCCGGGTCTGTGCTGAGGAGAACGCTGCTCCGCCTCCGCGGTACTCCGGACATATGTGCAGAGAAGAACGCAGCTGCGCCCTCGCCATGCTCTGCGAGTCTCTGCTGATGAGAACACAGCTTCACTTTCGCAAAGGCGCAGCGCCGGCGCAGGCGCGGAGGGGCGCGCAGCGCCGGCGCAGGCGCGGAGGGGCGCGCCCGAACCCGAACCCTAATGCCGTCATAAGAGCCCTAGGGAGACCTTAGGGAACAAGCATTAAACTGACACTCGATTCTGTAGCCGGCTCTGCCAAGAGACATGGCGTTGCGGTGATATGAGGGCAGGGGTCATGGAAGAAAGCCTTCTGGTTTTAGACCCACAGGAAGATCTGTGACGCGCTCTTGGGTAGAGCACACGTTGCTGGGCGTGCGCTTGAAAAGAGCCTAAGAAGAGGGGGCGTCTGGAAGGAACCGCAACGCCAAGGGAGGGTGTCCAGCCTTCCCGCTTCAACACCTGGACACATTCTGGAAAGTTTCCTAAGAAAGCCAGAAAAATAATTTAAAAAAAAATCCAGAGGCCAGACGGGCTAATGGGGCTTTACTGCGACTATCTGGCTTAATCCTCCAAACAACCTTGCCATACCAGCCCATCAGTCCTCTGAGACAGGTGAAGAACCTGAGGTCGCAGGAGGACACCCAGAAGGTCCAGAGAGAGCCTCCTAGGCCCCCCACCTCCCCCCGTGGCAGCTCCAACCCCAGCTTTTTCACTAGTAAGGCAGTCGGGCCCCTGGGCCACGCCCACTCCCCCAAGCGGGGAAGGAGCTTCGCGCTGCCGCTTGGCTGGGGACTGGGCACCGCCCTCCCGCGGCTCCTGAGCCGGCTGCCACCAGGGGGCGCGCCAGCGGTGTCCGGGAGCCTAGCGGCGCGTGTGCAGCGGCCAGTGCACCTGCTCTGGCCCTCGCCGCGGTCTCTGCCAGGACCCCGACGCCCAGCCTGACCCTGCCATTCAGCGGGGCTGCGGCTCCACGGCCTGCGACAGCAGCCCCACCTGGCATTCAGCGCGCTCCCGGGGGCAGAGGTCGCGGTGTCCTCACGCTGTGGTGCCGGCCTACAACCCCCACGCCGGGCTCGGGCCCGGCGGAGGAGGGCGATGCTCCCCGGGTAGGACAAACCGGTCACCTGGGCTGCGACGGCGGCTTAGGGGCAGAAGCGGCGGTCCAGGGCCGCCTGGCGCAGCAGCCTGTCCCAGCCGCGGTCCCTGCAGTCCCTCCCTGGCGGCTGCGCAGCCGTCCCACGACAGGGGCCATAAACTCTCCAGAGCGGAAAGCCGCACCCTGGTGGCCCGGCCCCGCGCCCAGACCTGGCGGCCGCTGGCACCTGACCCGCTGCATGGGTCTCCAGGGAGCTCGCTGCCCACCCGGCGCTGCAGGCTCGGCTCCCTCGTACACTCTCTGGTAGGTGCTAGGGACGACCCTATGGGCCAGCTTGCCATGCCCAGTCCCCAGGCCGCACCCACCCTGGCTCCCTGGGCTAGGGGACTGGCTCCTCCTGTGAGTCGTGGGTCTGGGAGGCAGGGGCGTTAGGGGAGAGTGAGGGACCGAGGGCAGCCCCTGCTGTGTGCACAGCGAGGTCGTGCACAGGCGTCTGTTGCAGAGCGTGCAGCTTCAGATGAGACTGGATTGCAGGTGGAGATGACTGTGGGTGCGCACACCTGGAGGTGAAGGGGAGGCAGCCTGTCTACCTGACCCATGAAATACAGGAGACTGTACCCCAGAAGCAGCGGGTTCACTGCTCCATTGATTAAGCAAGTCTGGGACACACATGTAGCTAAGCTGTGAGTTCTGTACCAGCGATCCCAACACCCACGCCCTCAGAAAGACACTGGTGTGGGGCCTGGGTGCTTGTCAGGCCTGAAAGTGGAGAGCACGGGCCAGAGACACTGAGTAGGGGGAACCCACCCTAGGGCTCTGAGGGACGACGATGTGGGGAGCTGGTGACAGAGCCTGAGCTGGCCCAATGTTGCACGGTGGGGACAGATTCGAGGTACAGTGGGGACTGGTGACCTCAGTTCCCAGTGTCCCAGCCTGGCCTCCCAGTCCACCCAGCAATTAGTGGGTGCTGCCCTGCAAAGACTCTGGGGGTGCCTCAGCCCTCCTCATCACACGTGACTGGTGACTTCTGTGTCCACCCGCACAATAAGAGGGATCTTCTCTCACTTTCAGGCAAGCCCAAGAAAGTCAGGGGCCTATGTGAGCCAAAGAGGAGAGAAGGTGATGCCTCAGCCCAGTGTTTCTGCCCCACCTCGCTTGTGGCCTTCGGAACTTGATTTGCACCGCAGGAAAATGGGCAATGAAAACCCCTCCCTAACTGGCTTCTCAGTCCACTCTGACCAGCCCACTGCACAGCGCCCACCCTGCAGCTCCAGGTACAGAGGCTGGGATGGCTCTGGGCTGACCTAAGGGCCTTCTGATGGCTCCAACCCTCGGGATGCCTCATGCTCACCCTTTGGCACCCACCTGACAGCTCAGCATCTCTGCTCTCTGCCATCCTCAATGCCTGCTCTAGACAAGCCCAAGTCCCCCAGGAGTGGCAGAGGGAACTGAGCCGAAAACTAAGTCTCGGCTCACTGAACCCCAAGTGGGCTGTCCAGCCTCGCCCTTCAGTTCACAACCCCAGGCAGGTTCCCTCCAGGGATGTGATCCCAGGGGCCACAGCAGCACATTCTGGCCTAACCTATCCACTATTTAAACAGTTACTGAAAAGGCCAGGATGGCCGTGGGCCCTGACATTAATCCCCTTTCTCTGTGAGGGGGCTGGGTTGGGTTTGCCATCCTGATGTCTTTGTGGAAAGAGCTGGCAGGTGAAGCAAGTCTCAGGGGCCAGCCATGGGACAAGGAACCTAGGACTGGCCTCTGCTGGAACCCTCTGAGGCCCCTGCGGACAGGAGGATCCAATGGAGGTCTAGCCACCCCTCCCAGGTTGGTGCTCACAGCCCCTCCCTGGCCCACTCCCTGCACACCTGCACCTGCTGGTCTCTGGGAGAGGAGCATCCATCCATCTTGTGCGCATAGCTTTCGGCTCCATTTTCATGAGGATGGTCTCCTTGGCAGAAATGCCCATTAGGGGATCCTGAGCCTGTGCTAGCTCTTCTCTAAGTGCCAAAGCCAGTGAGAGGGACTTGAAAACTCAAGACTTATTAACAGTATTTTCTGCATTTTGTGCTTTCAGGGTTGTTTTTTCCTTAAAATGTGTAAAAACAAACATTGAGATTTCTATCTTTTATATAATTTGGATTCTGTTATCACACGGACTTTTCCTGAAATTTATTTTTATGTATGTATATCAAACATTGAATTTCTGTTTTCTTCTTTACTGGAATTGTTAACTGTTTTATAGGCCAAATCTTTTAAAAAAAACACATCTCTCTAATTTCTCTAAACATTTCTAATTACATATATATTTACTATACCTAATACACTACTTTGGAATTCCTTGAGGCCTAAATGCATCGGGGTGCTCTGGTTTTGTTGTTGTTATTTCTGAATGACATTTACTTTGGTGCTCTTTATTTTGCGTATTTAAAACTATTAGATCGTGTGATTATATTTGACAGGTCTTAATTGACGCGCTGTTCAGCCCTTTGAGTTCGGTTGAGTTTTGGGTTGGAGAATTTTCTTCCACAAGGGATTGTCTTGGATTTTTCTGTTTCTCCCTCAATATCCACCTGGAAAACATTTCAATTAATTTATATTTACTTAAATATTTCTGTGCAAAAACTGTGTACAAAAGCCCCAAAGCATAATTTGTGCAGTTGAGCGCATGTTCTGTTGTTCAGCATTTATGGTGGTTGGTAGTGGAAAAGATTTTTAGAATATGTGGATTTTCGGGATATTCCCAGAAGCCCAGATAGCGACACTTTACCTTTGGAGGAATTACTTCTCAGAATATTGCACACAATCAATCGCCTTTGGAAGGAGCATATATCCCCAGCAAAAGCTCTGGTTTTTTGAAGTCTGTATTGTGTGTTACTTCCAGGAGAATATGCAATGATGACAATGTTATTAGATGATTCAAATATGAAGTGCTGTTATGCCAAACAATGAATCTTTGTGTTATACATTATGCCTAACTATAAATCTTTGTGTTATACATTTTAATGTCATTGGAGAGTACTCCTGTCTTCTTGGCATTATTGATAATTAGATTCTAATTGCTAATAAGTCAGAAAAATTAGGAACACCAAATTTCAGTTGTCTCAAAAGCACTCCTCTTATTAAATTTGGATGTTTACCTTTATCACATCAAAAGAAATATTGTTAGAAAGGTGTTTAATGTTTTGCAGATGGATAGATTACTGTTATTAGTTCTCATTTCATTGTTAATTTTTAAAACCATAAGGTTGGAAGTATCAATATGCCTTTCAATATACCTTAGTGGAATTTATTAAATTTTCATGGATGTCCTTTAGGGGGTTCAGGAAGTTATTTCTATTGCTAGATTTCTGGAAGATTTATCAGGAATGAGTGTCAGACATTGTCAGACGTCCATTGAAATCATCATGGTCTTTTCCTTTATTCTATTAATATGATGTATTACACTGATTGATTTTTAAATTTGTATTGGTAGGATAATTCCACTTGGTTATATTGTCTAACTTTTTTCTAATTTTCTTTCATTTTTATTACAGATGAGGCCTCACTCTGTCACCCAGGTTGGGGTGGAGTGGCACAGTCACAGCTCACTATAACCTCAAGCTCCTGGGCTCAAGTGATCCTGCCACCTCAGCCTCCTAAGTAGCTGGAACTACAGATGTGCACTGCCATGCCAGGCTTGTCTAACATTTTTATGTGTTGCTTCATCCAGTTTGCTAGAGTTTTTGGAGATTTCTGTCTTCATTCATGAGGGATAATAGTCTGCACTTTTATTTTCTTGTGATACTTTTGTCTGATTTGTTATCTGGGTAATACTGGCCTTGAAAATGAATTGATGTTTTCCTGCTTCTCTGCTTTGCAAGTGTTTGTGAAGGATTGGTTATTCATTAAGTGTTTAATAGAATTCACTAGTGAAGCTATGTGAGCCAGGGCTAGACTGATGAAGAGTTTTCATTAGTCTAATCTGTTTACTTGCTGTATAAGTACGCATATATTCTCTTTCTTCTTGATTTAATTTTACACTTTGTGTATAGCAGGGAATCTGTGTCTAATTTGTAGTATTTCATGCTTCTAGGTTTTCATGGCAGTTGAGATGTAAGAATAACAATAATGTTGGGAGAAGGAAGTTGTGGACAATCCATGAATATCCCAACATCTGTTGTAGGAAGGTTAAGATTACTTTTTTTTTTTTTGCTGTACTGAACTGAATACTCTTATTTATAATGTCAGACAAATGTAATGTTGTATATAAATAGAACTAGGAAAATGTGCCATTTGTCTTAGTATTTAATCAAGATGGAAGTCTGGGCCTACCTCCTCTCTTTTATTAATATGTAGACAGGACACCAACACAAATTAGAATGAAGACAAACAAAATGTTAGCAAATGAAGAATGGTATCAATTGGTTAAAATGTGATGAAATAGAGTGGTGAATATTTACATAGAATCCATGATGTGTTAGGTGCTATTTCAAGCTATTTGCACATATAGTTTTAATACCAATGACGTTAAAATGTATAACACAAAGATTCATATAAATAAAAATTACAACATTGTAAATAATATTAGGTGACACTAAAACTGTCATAGAAATACACATTTATATAAAACATAAAGTAACATGAAGTATTAAATTTTAGAAACTTTGATTACTAATCAGATGAACAACTGATTAGCCTTTTTATCCAGTAAAAAAGGCATACATATTATTTTCAAATTCCAGAGACAAATATTTTAAATATTGAAGTTGAAGACCTAAAAATGTGTCACTGACCTCATGGAAGTAGATATTCACTAGGTGATATTTTCTAGGCTCTCTGAAATTATATCAGAAAAATGTGAATTAGAATATAACCCATAAATAATATCTGGCCACATACAAAGTAATTGAAGATCAATTTAAATGGCTATTGGATTAAGAAATAGGGACTGAGGTAAATTTGCAGTGTCAGGGAGGATCTAAGGAGGAAGCATTGACACTGGAGCCCAAGGACCTGGGATCACAGAACAGATTCTACCAGTGCTAACTTACTGCTCCACAGAAAACATCAATTCTGCTCATGCGCAGGTACAATTCATCAAGAAAGGAATTACAACTTCAGAAATGTGTTCAAAATATATCCATACTTTGACATATTAATGAAGTAATCACATTCTACACATAACTACTCCATATGGAATACTGGGGAGGAGGTGTTCCAAATAAAGAGACTGAGGATTTCTCATGAGAACTCAGTGTCTGCTAGAAAATATCTAAGTAAAATATTTTACTTATGTGGAAAGTGTGGATGTTTGTGCATCAAAAGTTTCAAGAATCCCTAAAATTTACAATGGAGATGAGGAGAAAATATCAGAATTTCCCAGCACCAGAAATAAGGCAAGAAAAAATTCAGAGGGGTTGTAAATGTGAAAAGCCAATGGCTGGTCACACAGCAACATTGATAACCTTGTGCCTGGACAACTAGAATAAATACATAAACATACACATTGAAAATATTTCCAATATTAGATCTCCCTCATGTGAGAACTAAATTATAAAGATTGAAGCATAGAAGAAAATAAGCTACCAGAATAAATTTGATTACACATAAATTTCTGATATTGAAACTGTCACAAATGTTTAAGTTGGTAGTGGAAGACAAAGGACATATAATCTTGGGAGTCCTAAGGCCCTGCCCACTGCCAGTCCCTCCACACTACTACAGCTGATGCTTTCTGGAAATCACCACCTCCTGGCAGGAGCCCAACCAGCACAAATATAGAGCATTAAACCACCAAAGCTAAGGAGGCTCACAGAGTCTATTGCACCCTTCACCACCTCCACTGGAACAGGCGCTGGTATCCATGGCTCAGAGACCCAAAGATGGTTCACATCACAGGGCTCTATGCAGACAACCCCCAGTACCAGCCCAAAGCCACGTAGACCTGCTGGGTGGCTAGACCCAGAAGAGAGACAACAATCAATGCACTTTGGCTTACAGGAAGCCATGCCCATAGGAAAAAGGGGAGAGTACTACGTCAAGGGAACACCCCGTGGGATGAAAGAGTCTGAACAACAGTCTTCAGCCCTAGACCTTTCCTCTGACAGAGTCTACCAAAATGAGAAGGAACCAGAAAACCAACCCTGGTAATCTGACAAAACAAGAATCTTCAACACCCCCCAAAAAATCACACCAGTTCATCACCAATGGATCCAAACAAAGAAGAAATCACTGATTCATCTAAAAAAAAATTCAGGTTAGTTATTAAGCTAATCAGGGAGGGGCCAGAGAAAGATGAAGCCCAATGCAAGAAAATCCAAAAAATGATACAATACGTGAAGGGAGAATTATTCAAGGAAATAGATAGCTTAAATAAAAAAATAAAAAATCAGGAAACTTTGGACGTACTTTTAGAAATGTGAAATGCTCTGGAAAGTCTCAGCAATAGAATTGAACAAGTAGAAGAAAGAAATTCAGAATTCGAAGACAAGGTCTTTGATTTAACCCAATCCAATAAAGACAAAGAAAAAAGAATAAGAAAATATGAGCAAAGTCTCCAAGGAGTCTGGCATTCTGTTAAATGATGAAACCTAACACTAATTGGTGTACCTGAGGAAGAAGTGAATTCTAAAAGCCAGGAAAACATATTTGGGAGAATAATCTAGGAAAACTTCCATGGCCTTGTGAGAGACCTAGACATCCAAATACAAGAACCACAAATAACACCTGGGAAATTCATCACAAAAAGATCTTAGCCTAGGCACATTGTCATTAGGTTATCCAAAGTTAAGACAAAGGAAAGAATCTTAAGAGCTGTGAGACAGAAGCACTAGGTAACCTATAAAGGAAAACCTGTCAAATTAACAGCAGATTTCACAGCAGGAACCTTACAAGCTAGATGGGATTGGGGCCCTTTCTTCAGCCTCCTCAAACAAAACAATTATCAGCCAAGAATTTTGTATCCAGCAAAACTAAACATCATATATGAAGGAAAGATACAGTCATTTTCAGACAAACAAATGCTGACAGAATTTGCCATTACCAAGCCAGGACTCTAAGAACTGCTAAAAGGAGCTCTAAATCATGAAACAAATCCTGGAAACACATCAAAACAGAACTTCATTAACGCATAAATCACACAGGACCTATAAAACAAAAATACAAGTTAAAAAACAAAAACAAAGTACAGAGGCAACAAAGAGCATGATGAAAGCAATGGTACCTCACTTTTTAATACTAATGTTGGTTGTAAATGGCTTAAATGCTCCACTTACAAGATACAGAACCACAGAATGGATAACAACTCACCAACTAACTATCTGCTGCCTTCAGGAGACTCACCTAACACATAACGACTTACATAAACTTAAGGAAAGTGGTAGAAAAAGGCATTTCATGCAAATGGACACCAAAAGCAAGCAGCAGTAACTATTCTCATATGAGACAAAACAAACTTTAAAGCAACAGTAGCTAAAAGAGACAAAGAGAGACAGTATATCATCTGTCACCTGACAGTCTCATCCAACAGAAAAATATGACAATCCTAAACATATGTGAACCTAACACTGGAGCTCCCAAATTTATAAAACAATTACTAGTAGACATAAGAAATAAGATAGACAGCAACACAATAATAGTGGGGGACTTCAATACTCCACTGACAGCACTAGACAGGTCATCAAGACAGAAAGTCAACAAAGAAACAATGGATTTAAACTATACTTTGGAACAAATGGACTTAACAGATATATATAGAACATTTCATCCAACAACCACAGAATACACATTCTATTCAACAGCACATGGAATTTTCTCCAAGATAGACCATATGATAGGCCATAAAATGAGTCTCAATAAATTTAAGAAAATTGAAATTGTATCACGCACTCTCTCACATCACAATGGAATAAAACTGAAAATCAACTCCAAAAGGAATCTTCGAAACCATGCAAATACATGGAAATTAAATAACCTGCTCCTGAATGAGCATTGGGTGAAAAACGAAATCAAGATGGAAATGTAAAAAATTTCTTCGAACTGGATGACACAACCTATCAAGACCTCTGGGATACAGCAAAGGCAGTGCTAAGAGGAAAGTTTATAGCACTAAACACCTACGTCGAAAAGTCTGAAAGAGCACAGACAATCTAAGTTCACATCTCAGGGAACTAGAGAAGGAGGAACAAGCCAAACCCAATCCCAGCAAACAAAGGAAATAACCAAGATCAGAGCAGAACTAAATGAAATTGACACAACAACAACAACAACAAAAATACAAAACATAAATAAAACAAAAATTTGGTTATTTGAAAAGATA'

def findStopCodon(dnaStr, startIndex, stopCodon):
    currIndex = dnaStr.index(stopCodon, startIndex+3)
    while (currIndex != -1):
        diff = currIndex - startIndex
        if (diff % 3 == 0):
            return currIndex
        else:
            currIndex = dnaStr.index(stopCodon, currIndex+1)
   return -1

def findGene(dna, where):
    startIndex = dna.index('ATG', where)
    if startIndex == -1:
        return ''
    taa_index = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, 'TAA')
    tag_index = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, 'TAG')
    tga_index = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, 'TGA')
    minIndex = 0
    if (taa_index == -1 | (tga_index != -1 & tga_index < taa_index)):
        minIndex = tga_index
    else:
        minIndex = taa_index
    if (minIndex == -1 | (tag_index != -1 & tag_index < minIndex)):
        minIndex = tag_index
    if minIndex == -1:
        return ""
    return dna[startIndex:minIndex + 3]

def printAllGenes(dna):
    startIndex = 0

    while True:
        currentGene = findGene(dna, startIndex)
        if len(currentGene) == 0:
            break

        print(currentGene)
        startIndex = dna.index(currentGene, startIndex) + len(currentGene)

printAllGenes(gene_sequence)
```

It outputs 29 genes and I'm not sure how much more could be found. The error in the line below is causing it to end before making it through the rest of the strand.

```
 currIndex = dnaStr.index(stopCodon, currIndex+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under an incorrect impression that `.index()` returns `-1` on failure to find the substring:

```
currIndex = dnaStr.index(stopCodon, startIndex+3)
while (currIndex != -1):
```

This is not the case, it throws an error instead:

```
>>> help(str.index)
Help on method_descriptor:

index(...)
    S.index(sub[, start[, end]]) -> int

    Like S.find() but raise ValueError when the substring is not found.

>>>
```

As the help explanation notes, you really want the `.find()` method.

Let's try to simply your code rather than just patch it:

```
gene_sequence = 'AAC...ATA'  # supply your original sequence here

STOP_CODONS = {'TAA', 'TAG', 'TGA'}

def findStopCodon(dnaStr, startIndex, stopCodons):

    for currIndex in range(startIndex + 3, len(dnaStr), 3):
        if dnaStr[currIndex:currIndex + 3] in stopCodons:
            return currIndex

    return -1

def findGene(dna, where):
    startIndex = dna.find('ATG', where)

    if startIndex == -1:
        return '', startIndex

    stopIndex = findStopCodon(dna, startIndex, STOP_CODONS)

    if stopIndex == -1:
        return '', stopIndex

    return dna[startIndex:stopIndex + 3], stopIndex + 3

def printAllGenes(dna):
    startIndex = 0

    while True:
        currentGene, startIndex = findGene(dna, startIndex)

        if not currentGene:  # empty strings are False
            break

        print(currentGene)

printAllGenes(gene_sequence)
```

This outputs 69 genes and doesn't break.  Test it to make sure it really does what you want.